# more optimized way to write if-else

Tags: java, if-statement

I am new to java what is right way to write if and else block with below code Please let me know what i have implemented wrong. And i have to use all this if..else block 3 times with different conditions . And I am getting all the output but i want to make it more optimized. I think that we can use constant class to make it more optimized

```
if (roleName.equalsIgnoreCase("Project Manager")) {
    if (actionsPerform.equalsIgnoreCase("Approval")) {
        reimbursementHistory.setOldStatus(0);
        reimbursementHistory.setNewStatus(1);
        reimbursementHistory.setAssignTo((String) reimbursementHistoryDetails.get("businessUnitId"));
        reimbursementHistory.setAssignne((String) reimbursementHistoryDetails.get("projectManagerId"));
    }
    else if (actionsPerform.equalsIgnoreCase("Query")) {
        reimbursementHistory.setOldStatus(1);
                                reimbursementHistory.setNewStatus(6);
        reimbursementHistory.setAssignne((String) reimbursementHistoryDetails.get("projectManagerId"));
        reimbursementHistory.setAssignTo((String) reimbursementHistoryDetails.get("empCode"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks ok. are you facing any issue with this?

Comment: @Tirth you missed the closing braces of outer if

Comment: Once you will get used to java, I suggest you try to use a POJO to store those parameters and store them in a `Map<String, Param>`. That will let you remove those `if-else` statements completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the complexity of the condition you have, I woudl store those parameters in a `Map` using a simple `POJO`.

```
private static final class Params{
    final int oldStatus;
    final int newStatus;
    final String AssignTo;
    final String AssignNe;

    public Params(int oldStatus, int newStatus, String assignTo, String assignNe) {
        this.oldStatus = oldStatus;
        this.newStatus = newStatus;
        this.AssignTo = assignTo;
        this.AssignNe = assignNe;
    }
}
```

Then create each parameters at first

```
private static Map<String, Params> params = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    params.put("Approval", new Params(0,  1, "businessUnitId", "projectManagerId"));
    params.put("Query", new Params(1,  6, "empCode", "projectManagerId"));
}
```

Then you just need to define a method to set the values

```
public boolean setHistory(Params p){
    reimbursementHistory.setOldStatus(p.oldStatus);
    reimbursementHistory.setNewStatus(p.newStatus);
    reimbursementHistory.setAssignTo((String) reimbursementHistoryDetails.get(p.AssignTo));
    reimbursementHistory.setAssignne((String) reimbursementHistoryDetails.get(p.AssignNe));
}
```

And call it using some method reference and `Optional`

```
Optional.of(params.get("Query"))
    .map(this::setHistory)
    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

Using an `Optional` allows to throw easily an exception if it is not found.

Comment: Thank you so much.. That was so informative.. yes i will surely try to implement it..